# "I love you so"

Tags: phrases

I've encountered (in songs, mostly) the phrase "*I love you so*". I understand what it means, but I can't make grammatical sense of it. It's very different in meaning from "*I think so*" or "*I told you so*".

- Is it a contraction of "*I love you so **much***"? Is it the other way around?
- Can the construction be used with other verbs, and in which context and register? I've only seen it with the verb *to love*.

Comment: I wouldn't *exactly* say it's a contraction of the specific "full version" *I love you so **much***. You could just as well say it came from *I love you so **dearly,*** or ***passionately***, for example. But realistically, it's better not to imagine it's necessarily a shortened version of *anything* that specific. It's just that those are a few alternative words we could tack on the end to make the syntax and/or meaning clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 90% answered your own question. 'So' is used as an adverb to mean 'so much', 'extremely', 'to such a degree', and [dictionaries specifically mention](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so) 'so' used at the end of a sentence to mean 'to a very great degree'.

So, you can use it with a variety of nouns.

> **I hate you so.**
>
> **I worry so.**
>
> **I fear him so.**

All of which said, in my experience it is a phrase which is, as you mentioned, more common in older songs and literature than in modern speech. To my mind it gives the impression of an Enid Blyton book from the 1930s.

> **George, you *are* beastly. I do hate you so!**

Today I would expect the average youth to say:

> **George, you're an ass. I hate you so much!**

Comment: You're right, but 1. I wasn't sure and 2. a fair 40% of my question was "*Why just 'love'? Can it be used with other verbs, and if not why?*"

Comment: Yeah - if not Enid Blyton, *any* poet (or any writer from more than a century or so ago). Without ***much*** (or similar) it's a somewhat dated / poetic / literary usage today.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I just meant your guess was almost right, and I'm very happy to give you the extra information you asked for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the extent to which I enjoyed writing that fake 1930s sentence is a clear sign of my encroaching decrepitude. I'm tempted to spend the rest of the day writing things like "I say Smitherington, you absolute rotter! Mr Tippins may forgive you, but I know I shan't."

Comment: Spoken (written?) like a true Edwardian toff! In *my* Blyton-reading youth, that use of ***shan't*** just implied "middle class" (to me, anyway), but today it seems almost "anachronistic".

Comment: You could alter the whole meaning by inserting a comma, as in: **I love you, so!** where **so** becomes an exclamation - meaning **so there, come to terms with that**.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that this is an elision (not strictly speaking a contraction) of "I love you so much". That specific phrase has been used so often that it is an idiom of its own, and continues to be used when other parallel phrases such as "I hate you so" are far less common.

(I disagree with other answers that this sounds like something from the 1930s. Indeed I use the phrase "I love you so" rather frequently myself -- to my wife.)

By the way, a contraction is when one or more letters are omitted, as "can't" for "cannot" or "don't" for "do not". An elision is when a word or words are implied and omitted, or even an entire sentence or more. the verb for making an elision is "to elide".